# How to copy resources with original permission in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a `UserManager.sh` in test/resources.When I run `mvn test`, maven copy `UserManager.sh` to `target/test-classes/` with incorrect permission.

My shell file permission is 705, but it was coped with 644.I have no special configuration about `maven-resources-plugin`.

```
zephyrdeiMac:Permission-Proxy zephyrguo$ ls -la src/test/resources/UserManager.sh 
-rwx---r-x  1 zephyrguo  staff  2232 May  6 17:11 src/test/resources/UserManager.sh

zephyrdeiMac:Permission-Proxy zephyrguo$ ls -la target/test-classes/UserManager.sh 
-rw-r--r--  1 zephyrguo  staff  2232 May 10 10:36 target/test-classes/UserManager.sh
```

Comment: Everything in src/test/resources or src/main/resources is copied with the permissions the user under which Maven is running copied. Furthermore why are copying shell script as resources? What is the purpose of that? Creating a resulting distribution package ?

Comment: i think here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521132/keep-permissions-on-files-with-maven-resourcestestresources) hope this helps