# Linux: The driver is not executable in target folder

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber

I have given permission chmod 777 to chromedriver.exe but when I am running "mvn clean test" I am getting the exception "driver is not executable". Each time the target folder getting deleted and generating permission issues.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521132/keep-permissions-on-files-with-maven-resourcestestresources) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Despite of the solution [@wjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/665657/wjans) suggests you to consider there also can be the case that you are using executable for Win OS. You mention that you cannot launch `chromedriver.exe` however Linux chromedriver executable does not have any extension.

Hence you are getting the error saying that Windows executable cannot be executed in Linux.