# How to preserve mode and line-endings, when bundling files?

Tags: maven, unix, maven-3

Our maven "build" consists of checking the files out from Git, and then bundling them -- verbatim -- into a "JAR":

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory></directory>
            <includes>
                <include>deployment/*</include>
                <include>foo/*</include>
                <include>scripts/**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

When checked out from Git, the files all have the correct-permissions (the scripts are 0755, for example), but, when we unzip the bundle, the permissions are all 644 and we have to fix them by hand.

Is that Maven's doing? Can the above `<build>` be modified to preserve the file-permissions?

Also, can it be told to force Unix line-endings on all files?

Comment: Please post the full pom file...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep permissions on files with Maven resources:testResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521132/keep-permissions-on-files-with-maven-resourcestestresources)

Comment: Thanks, @Pino, the answer there links to a [Maven bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-236) -- and suggests a work-around. But the bug is [now closed](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared-utils/pull/29) -- yet, we still have the problem. Is our Maven too old (and does not have the fix), or does the above XML-snippet need changing?

I don't want to implement a work-around -- we already have one...

Comment: @khmarbaise, the full `pom.xml` is small, but has references to our internal servers so I'd rather not post it all. There is nothing in it other than group, artifactId, version declarations, and the `<scm>` section pointing at our Git-repository. And then -- the above `<build>` part.

Comment: In such cases I would recommend to use the maven-assembly-plugin which allows to set permissions etc...

Comment: But why do I need to set permissions (again), when they are maintained in git already?